# Using WSPBuilder to build a solution for a web part I developed

Tags: sharepoint, wspbuilder, wsp

I have only ever deployed web parts from development by clicking F5. Now, I know I have to have a manifest file, feature file, etc and it all goes into a wsp file. I understand the wsp file is what gets added to Central Admin.

So my problem is this. I have found lots of sites that show how to use WSP Builder, but they don't seem to show how/where I add my web part to the WSP Builder project. My understanding is that somehow I should be able to use WSP Builder to create a wsp file containing my already-developed web part.

There are only two approaches that I see would work.

1. I create a WSPBuilder project (like all the how-tos on WSPBuilder show), then I assume I would somehow add my web part to that project - although I don't know how.
2. In my web part project, create WSPBuilder -> Build WSP. I have done this, and when I run stsadm on the resulting wsp file, I get it in Central Admin, but its not added to my Site Collection Features or my Web Part Gallery.

Can someone please explain this to me like I am a 6 year old? If you point me to another site, there is a good chance I have already seen it, so then I would ask you point me to the specific lines that tell me how to get my already existing web part packaged into the wsp.

Answer (score 2):

To create a new web part feature with WSPBuilder:

1. Right-click on the name of your WSPBuilder project in Visual Studioand click **Add**, **New Item**.
2. Select WSPBuilder from the tree on the left and choose **Web Part Feature** from the list on the right of the dialog.
3. Enter the title of the web part feature and click **OK**.
4. In the dialog that appears enter the title, description and scope and click **OK**.

Your feature will now be created. You will then need to merge your existing web part code into this feature and configure its XML files.

Read [this walkthrough](http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2009/04/08/wspbuilder-walkthrough-of-the-visual-studio-add-in.aspx) by Tobias Zimmergren for more information. There is [another walkthrough](http://rasor.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/wss-dev-quickstart/) here.

Comment: Thanks Alex. That is a valuable answer.

Answer (score 0):

Alex, got the right path to solve it. I think the small exception here is that wrongly spelt **Add New Item** instead of **New Project**.