# Creating webparts in visual studio

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, sharepoint

i have visual studio 2008 standard .i have MS Sharepoint desighner 2007.Do i need any other software for creating webparts.I dont know how to proceed.Please help

Answer (score 1):

You will need to

1. Install Sharepoint on your dev machine. WSS3.0 or MOSS2007 should be alright, but you should compare the difference in features between the 2 to decide whether you will need to pay for MOSS2007: 
   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14117#overview
2. Install VS2008 extensions for Sharepoint, which will give you the project templates to get started in visual studio: 
   http://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/details.aspx?id=841
3. A Sharepoint environment to deploy and test your web part.

Here's a link with a pretty good tutorial on getting started:
http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2009/04/01/build-and-debug-web-parts-with-sharepoint-extensions.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [WSPBuilder](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1260347/1206300) you can find explanations of how to create `web part` by WSPBuilder.